# When can you weed and feed new sod?

Tags: lawn, grass, fertilizer

Two weeks ago I laid down new sod on the lawn. I'm watering it really well, and it is greening up. So far no issues with it.

My question is, is it too early to weed and feed it?

*Note: It is [centipede grass](http://www.american-lawns.com/grasses/centipede.html).*

Answer (score 4):

Weed and feed products are best not used in centipede grass, so you should only use a lawn fertilizer which isn't too high in nitrogen, more info on centipede grass and fertiliser here

http://www.todayshomeowner.com/when-and-how-to-fertilize-centipede-grass/

Given its only been laid for two weeks its probably too soon to apply fertilizer, it takes around 4 to 6 weeks for sods to root into the soil beneath, but centipede grass is best fed after green up in spring but before temperatures reach 85 degF - whether there'll be time to wait another two weeks or so before that happens rather depends on where you live. You could try gently lifting one of the sods to see whether its rooted in, but don't tug too hard and test one in the midst of the area, not at the outer edges. The outer edges are usually the last to root in.

More information here from Scotts - if they're anything like Scotts in the UK, they have an information and advice line (because they assume you're using their products) so that might be worth trying

http://www.scotts.com/smg/goART3/Howto/how-to-plant-centipede-grass/33800019

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I use Southern Weed and Feed (http://www.scotts.com/smg/goprod/lawn-bonus-s-weed-and-feed-3/prod90008). It explicitly indicates centipede.  Would you think this is safe still with centipede?

Comment: well that's odd, because the scotts site suggests using a different product for centipede, with low, slow release nitrogen. Have a look at the link I provided, scroll down to the bit about fertilizing/feeding